# How to add two lists with the same amount of index's in python

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I am still new to coding so i apologize for the basic question. How do I add to elements of two seperate lists?

```
listOne = [0, 1 , 7, 8]
listTwo = [3, 4, 5, 6]
listThree = []

for i in listOne:
    listAdd = (listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
    listThree.append(listAdd)
print(listThree)
```

I want the output to be `[3, 5, 12, 14]` but i keep getting a syntax error saying

```
TypeError: List indices must be integers, not strings.
```

I thought this may have to do with i possibly being a string so i put `int(i)` as the first line after the for loop but this did not help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `zip()` function. Change the `+` to whatever operation you want.

```
listOne = [0, 1 , 7, 8]
listTwo = [3, 4, 5, 6]

l = [x + y for x, y in zip(listOne, listTwo)]

print(l)

[3, 5, 12, 14]
```

Comment: when I do this, it outputs [03, 14, 75, 86]. I didn't post the whole code (I tried to simplify it a bit and that may be my problem) but i have two while loops that allow for two lists to be made with the append function. I think the error may be in there. Would it help if i posted it?

Comment: @DonnieB - In that case, the code you posted in your question is wrong. Your lists contain strings, not integers. You should accept an answer and then ask a new, corrected question.

Comment: I agree with @TigerhawkT3. Integers and strings are added differently. The way you described it is most likely string behaviour

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map` with the `add` function from the `operator` module:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> listOne = [0, 1 , 7, 8]
>>> listTwo = [3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> map(add, listOne, listTwo)
[3, 5, 12, 14]
```

Comment: This is the best answer according to me, however it should be explained that what map does is that it in this case iterates `operator.add` over `listOne` and `listTwo`, so what it is doing is basically what @Leb and @Donaldv suggested: `[x + y for x,y in zip(listOne, listTwo)]`. Also lookup [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

```
print np.array(list1) + np.array(list2)
```

thats all.

Comment: That concatenates the lists, it doesn't perform an element-wise addition

Comment: oh thats what I get for not reading the question :P @ChadSimmons

Comment: fixed :P there we go @EdChum

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why would you get the error you posted. Where is the rest of the code? Where is listThree initialized?

The error you made is that you are iterating over the list elements, but then you act as if you're iterating over the indices. There is no listOne[8], for instance. What you seem to be trying to do is:

```
listThree = []
for i in range(len(listOne)):
    listThree.append(listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
print(listThree)
```

Though better still would be to avoid the for-append all together and use a list comprehension.

```
listThree = [ listOne[i]+listTwo[i] for i in range(len(listOne)) ]
print(listThree)
```

Comment: @Chad Simmons - I wrote it in a similar fashion to what Donnie wrote, to emphasize where he got things wrong. Indeed the one-liner is much better, but perhaps it should be added to the first way, and not replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You are making two things wrong

1. You're using the element's of listOne in your for
2. You don't create your variable outside the for's scope.

Seem's dificult, but it's pretty simple

```
listOne = [0, 1, 7, 8]
listTwo = [3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in listOne:
    listAdd = (listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
    listThree.append(listAdd)
print(listThree)
```

Look at your for, the "i" variable it's assuming this values:
0, 1, 7, 8

That's because you use "i in listOne", so, "i" it's assuming the values of listOne.

The right way to do it is:

```
listOne = [0, 1, 7, 8]
listTwo = [3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(len(listOne)):
    listAdd = (listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
    listThree.append(listAdd)
print(listThree)
```

Now the "i" will assume this values: "0, 1, 2, 3", because now you're using the length of listOne in your for.

But there's another thing. This is a little more dificult but you NEED to know.

When you declare a variable inside a block of code (inside an if, while, for...), it's die when the program go out of that block. For example:

```
x = 30
if x is 30:
   stringInsideIf = "Hello World"
print(stringInsideIf)
```

In this example, you gonna receive and Error, because "stringInsideIf" it's not declared outside the if's block.

So, you need to declare "listThree" outside the for's block, as a new list, like this

```
listThree = []
```

I think it will solve the problem

And don't be afraid to ask basic questions, no one born as a programmer

Comment: Thanks for the help. Explanations on why something does or does not help are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create listThree outside the for loop.

listOne = [0, 1 , 7, 8]

listTwo = [3, 4, 5, 6]

listThree = []

for i in listOne:

```
listAdd = (listOne[i] + listTwo[i])

listThree.append(listAdd)
```

print(listThree)

Thats all. Coding is easy to learn explain to the computer how you yourself would explain it to yourself. Happy Coding :-)

Comment: You're right! I had it in the original code but i tried to edit parts out to make it shorter and simpler.

Comment: @DonnieB Glad I could help let me know if you have anymore questions. Take care, Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with others that there are better ways (list comprehension, built-in libraries, etc.) but here is how to minimally fix your code:

```
for i in range(len(listOne)):
    listAdd = (listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
    listThree.append(listAdd)
```

The key being that you are trying to iterate through the list **indices**, not its values (which is what you get from "for i in listOne:").

len(listOne) gives the length of the list (here: 4)

range(4) -> (0, 1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 0):

for i in listOne -->here i represents elements of list not indexes

```
listOne = [0, 1 , 7, 8]
listTwo = [3, 4, 5, 6]
listThree = []

for i in range(len(listOne)):
    listAdd = (listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
    listThree.append(listAdd)
print(listThree)
```

Above code will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you're getting that particular error.  You actually should be getting index out of range exceptions.  That's what I get when I paste your code into my interpreter.  The reason for that is this.
When you say

```
for i in listOne:
   listAdd = (listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
   listThree.append(listAdd)
```

i is actually equal to the value of the item in the list at each iteration, so 0 then 1, then 7, then 8.  So when you try and access the elements of listOne and listTwo using i as the index, it will fail when i is a number larger than the location of the last item in the list.

There's many ways to accomplish what you want.  You could do this

```
for i in range(4):
   listAdd.append(listOne[i] + listTwo[i])
```

You could also do this

```
for x,y in zip(listOne, listTwo)
   listAdd.append(x+y)
```

These are some of the most looplike ways to do it.  leb and Donald showed the list comprehension style above, Dan demonstrated map.